# How do I send a list of connected clients from the server to the client, differentiating between a regular message?

Tags: c#, winforms, sockets, tcp

I am rather new to network programming. I have done tons of googling and research over the past few days and have a chat application that can have multiple users connected to the server and are able to send messages to each other.

Right now there are no catches or methods for a client disconnecting, which I will add at a later date. However right now, I wish to add the functionality of showing a list of online users in a textbox on my client-side form.

When a client connects to the server, the server adds this client to the 'clientList'. However, I am a bit confused on how I would go about sending this list over to the client, but more importantly, how I would make the client recognise that this is not a regular message, more-so a list of clients.

I thought about making it so it sends it with a unique string of characters and doing an if statement, but I know there is a better way of doing it.

On the client-side code, I have a background worker that listens for data from the server. Surely if I serialise the list into a binary formatter, it will be picked up by my 'message listener', and the program will get confused on what is a message and what is data for the connected clients. Therefore I am not sure how I would differentiate between the two.

By no means am I asking you to code for me. I am simply looking for advice from those who have more wisdom and experience in the field. If I could get some pointers on the best way to approach this, I would be more than grateful. I appreciate your time.

Cient side code --

```
   using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace socketClientForm
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            private static byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            private static Socket clientSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            public string message = "";
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                this.Text = "Client";
            }

            delegate void SetTextCallback();

            private void SetText()
            {
                if (this.InvokeRequired)
                {
                    SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(SetText);
                    this.Invoke(d, new object[] { });
                }
                else
                    this.chatBox.AppendText(message);
            }

            private void LoopConnect()
            {
                int attempts = 0;

                while (!clientSocket.Connected)
                    try
                    {
                        attempts++;
                        clientSocket.Connect(IPAddress.Parse(IPBox.Text), 8080);
                    }
                    catch (SocketException)
                    {
                        chatBox.Clear();
                        chatBox.AppendText("Connection attempts: " + attempts.ToString());
                    }

                clientSocket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync), clientSocket);
                chatBox.Clear();
                chatBox.AppendText("Connected \n");
            }

            private void submitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(msgBox.Text))
                {

                    string req = usernameBox.Text + ": " + msgBox.Text;
                    byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(req);
                    clientSocket.Send(buffer);
                    msgBox.Text = "";
                }
            }

            private void connectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                LoopConnect();
            }

            private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
            {
                while (clientSocket.Connected)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        byte[] receivedBuf = new byte[1024];
                        int rec = clientSocket.Receive(receivedBuf);
                        byte[] data = new byte[rec];
                        Array.Copy(receivedBuf, data, rec);

                        message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data) + "\n";
                        SetText();
                    }
                    catch
                    {

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Server side code --

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace socketServer
{
    class Program
    {
        private static byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        private static List<Socket> clientSockets = new List<Socket>();
        private static Socket serverSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "Server";
            SetupServer();
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static void SetupServer()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Setting up server...");
            serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 8080));
            serverSocket.Listen(1);

            serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallBack), null);
        }

        private static void AcceptCallBack(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.EndAccept(AR);
            clientSockets.Add(socket);
            Console.WriteLine("Client Connected");
            socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), socket);
            serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallBack), null);
        }

        private static void ReceiveCallBack(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;

            int received = socket.EndReceive(AR);
            byte[] dataBuff = new byte[received];
            Array.Copy(buffer, dataBuff, received);

            string text = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(dataBuff);
            Console.WriteLine("Text received: " + text);

            byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(text);

            foreach (Socket client in clientSockets)
            {
                client.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), client);
                client.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), client);
            }

            //socket.BeginSend(data, 0, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), socket);
            //socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), socket);
        }

        private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult AR)
        {
            Socket socket = (Socket)AR.AsyncState;
            socket.EndSend(AR);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you could use the first byte as an identifier. So each identifier has a certain meaning. This way you can distinguish whether it is a valid message or some additional information that you are sending. According to the identifier you would place the incoming string at different target controls

Comment: Ahh okay thank you. So essentially, have a method / background worker in my server that will repeatedly send data to all clients, giving them a list of connected clients. The data the server sends will always have a character before it, such as perhaps an "M" for message, and a "D" for data. The client listener will always do a check to see if the string starts with a D or M, and if so, it would then allocate the next incoming data into the appropriate control? For sending the client data, would I do that through a list serialisation? Or join and split the string based on commas? Thanks!

Comment: TCP Sockets is **not** messaging. You are not guaranteed that each call to `Send` at one end will be matched by a single call to `Receive` at the other end. If you want *messages*, it's up to *you* to implement those on top of TCPs endless stream of bytes in both directions. Or, to make things simpler on yourself, to move to a higher level protocol that already *does* messaging over TCP.

Comment: @Damien, I'm sorry what do you mean? By messages I mean bytes  that are first sent to the server which are then broadcasted to all clients, converted to a string and are displayed in a chatbox, which my application does. Like an instant chat messaging service over LAN. I am simply using the same classes and namespace as almost everyone on google is regarding "C# Chat application", and they don't seem to have a problem accomplishing what I am trying to do.

Comment: Yes, but I'm saying that if you do `Send(<some array containing 20 bytes>)` you are *not* guaranteed that some call to `Receive` is going to deliver you exactly 20 bytes. It may deliver you 10 bytes now and the remaining bytes the next time you call `Receive`. Or it may deliver 35 bytes, with 15 of those bytes being from the next "message" that the client sent, etc. You don't get discreet *messages*, you're just sending an endless stream of bytes and TCP doesn't guarantee the size of the chunks it delivers to the other end.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever as I said before I have simply used the same classes and namespaces as I have seen when googling how to make a chat application, and almost everything is using Sockets. If not using sockets, what else do you recommend I use? I haven't experienced any dataloss or corruption so-far when messaging.

Comment: ", it would then allocate the next incoming data into the appropriate control?" basically yes, that is the idea. "For sending the client data, would I do that through a list serialisation?" I don't really understand what you mean. You can only send bytes. "Or join and split the string based on commas?" that is entirely up to you.

Comment: But since the TCP protocol is not 100% reliable you could sometimes loose the first byte or as Damien already said you are not guaranteed to receive the entire message in one blow. So if you send `MHello` and then `DMarco` you could receive `MHelloD` and `Marco` Which according to your logic you both end up in the messaging window. But this would not be your intention

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is harder to derive a messaging protocol if you are working with plain bytes and string messages.
You are best creating a model - something like

```
public class NetMessage{

public int MessageType{get;set;}
public dynamic Payload{get;set;}

}
```

So lets imaging MessageType 1 is your authentication request.

it would be something like

```
 {    "MessageType":"1",    "PayLoad":{
                 "Username":"Admin",
                 "Password":"Password123"
              }

 }
```

You can either serialize this to string and send it (via Newtonsoft.Json)
Or, as I prefer, using a binary formatter to convert the object to bytes directly and then sending the bytes over the network.
Sending the serialized to byte form data, will be just slightly more efficient than sending string info across the network.

Using the protocol described above, you can make your server perform a switch statement on the MessageType and then handle the logic differently.

In your question, you want to send a list of connected clients?

Use something like MessageType 99, and set the Payload to be a List of clients.
Just remember, you cannot serialize the TcpClient object and send it to a remote user and expect the object to function like a connected TcpClient.
You can at most send the remote ip and the port that the server is connected to.
So I would recommend sending a model that represents this data.

UPDATE:

At the moment, your background worker is receiving the data and processing it as byte -> text and then performing straight up business logic on the text.

What you should be using, is managed types, other than the string type.
String is too low level, you need some intermediary types to help manage the logic.

Use nuget package manager in visual studio to install Newtonsoft.Json
(or JSON.Net it is sometimes known as)

With Newtonsoft you can do the following.

Given a class that looks like this

```
public class MessageClass
{
    public int MessageType{get;set;}
    public dynamic Payload{get;set;}
}
```

You can do the following

```
string content = "{\"MessageType\":\"2\",\"Payload\":\"blah\"}";
```

This is a JSON formatted string, that represents a class instance.

In C# Code this object would be like this:

```
var message = new MessageClass();
message.MessageType=2;
message.Payload = "blah";
```

What Newtonsoft gives you, is the ability to turn strings into managed C# types.
Eg:

Remember our string above called 'content' ?

```
var managedObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MessageClass>(content);
Console.WriteLine(managedObject.MessageType);  // will; write 2
```

What I propose, is that your client and server communicate via JSON Formatted objects which then gives you the ability to perform more advanced conditional statements and more accurate assertions.

Newtonsoft provides 2 key methods for you to use.
Documented on the newtonsoft website.
newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/Methods_T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert.htm

To turn a C# object into a string
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object o);
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(String value);

For the deserialize method, put the type you are deserializing it to, in where the T is.

Eg:

```
MessageClass msg = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MessageClass>(content);
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, it is greatly appreciated. This is quite advanced, I have never seen or used "public dynamic" before nor have I worked with this type of data transfer. I'm sure I will get there. How would the client understand if the data is a message and to display in the chatbox, or if the data is a list of clients to display in the "connected:" box? I also don't know how I would convert the instance of the 'NetMessage' class into a byte. Would I then be able to extract it in the client and create a new instance of X class? It would still recognise the data as a class?

Comment: You could use the MessageType to determine which course of action to take.
If MessageType is 2 = it is a chat message, so you cast the Payload to string content, to display in the chat box. If the MessageType is 99, then treat it as a List<string> - so you can iterate through the list of strings. dynamic is sometimes treated as a dirty type of class, because it can be considered lazy. It allows you to have variables / properties that contain any type of data, but it then becomes your responsibility to manage that variable appropriately.

Comment: But as far as the client is concerned, all data coming in is handled via the same background worker, listening for bytes. Are you suggesting that on the client I convert the bytes to string, the string being "MessageType1: Data Goes Here". Based on the value of message type 1 I have a switch statement on the client that either puts the data into the chatbox, or the client name box? I don't care about being able to use the functionality of TCP Client, or do anything else with the socket. I simply just want to display a list of connected clients for the user to see "Jim is online". Thanks bud.

Comment: I will update my answer with an example - but basically, performing your program logic on the string content of the message you are receiving reduces your ability to assert of certain business scenarios. You should use a more managed type of message - see my example in a few mins.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have marked your answer as 'correct answer', even though I have not implemented this advice yet, as it is extremely inclusive and goes into great detail. I am sure it will help not only me but others that come across it. So just to confirm that I am understanding correctly, have a `MessageClass` on both the server and client. When sending data from one to the other, it is serialised and then deserialised on the receiving end, creating an instance of the `MessageClass`, or alternatively just have the string in the JSON format already on the server. Using Newtonsoft ofc.

Comment: Thats correct, You will find that you can accomplish more advanced functionality by using managed types. You can work programmatically with your messages and then feed them into a 'Send' function - which then takes care of the serialization and transmission for you. This is the road to building your messaging protocol. The only other thing to be aware of is that the MessageClass definition needs to be identical on the client and the server. It is essentially a blueprint - if it is different on client or server, then it may not deserialize correctly.

Comment: As a quick update, I just wanted to say thank you for your assistance. I have been able to implement your advice and the application is much more stable and works exactly as intended. I have much more control. Thank you again!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked out for you. Thanks for the feedback, its nice to hear when a recommendation has a positive effect.